# Adding hair particles in particle edit mode

Tags: particles

So I set my emission number to zero and decided to add my eyelashes manually. In the "add" section, I have the radius way down and the count at one, but when ever I try to add a hair, it doesn't apply where I want it to. I did this with the eyebrows and it worked just fine. Not sure what's going on...  Hopefully a quick fix.

Link to my .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6xONZ2msgKHT1p2cEw5akZ5Yms/edit?usp=sharing

[image: This is what happens. My mouse is where I clicked]

my mouse is where i clicked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the particle system above the subsurf modifier in the *Modifier stack* by pressing the up arrow:

[image]

The resulting order should be something like

1. The two particle systems
2. The Subsurf modifier

E.g.:

[image]

Comment: I did this but I'm still getting seperation from the hair root and mesh after subdividing in the stack. Is there a way for the hair to emit and take the subdiv into consideration?

Comment: @SiasJordaan To do that you'll want the particle system(s) to be *below* the subsurf modifier. You'll also need to enable [*Use modifier stack*](http://blender.org/manual/physics/particles/emission.html#distribution-settings) for each particle system